# Java Deployment configuration issue

Tags: java, deployment

I'm having the worst time trying to make the Java Update window stop popping up for people in my company. We have to instruct them to click "do not ask again" and "later" very frequently and if they click update or block, it causes a ton of issues and extra work for me.

When we do our java updates, we intend to deploy them with SCCM, and none of the users are admins, so they cannot update even if they wanted to. I want to find a way to disable that popup in IE asking if they want to update Java to where it'll automatically assume "later" and to never ask.

I've tried some registry entries that I've read about that did nothing (HKLM/SOFTWARE/JavaSoft/Policy) and I've tried the C:\Windows\Sun\Java\Deployment files and they seem to not even be trying to work.

I'm lost and this has become a super time consuming issue for me. Any help is super appreciated.

Note: we only run 32 bit Java due to some website we used that won't work with x64.

Comment: Did you try asking at the https://superuser.com/ forum?

Comment: No, I tried asking here. I've been scouring the web for a good answer for the past 3 days before finally asking.

Comment: Try to ask there, there are more professionals for these type of questions. Stackoverflow is more helpful with development questions and not administration

Comment: Yeah I asked there after you suggested it and they put it "on hold" because I'm asking about a corporate environment.

Comment: Okay to simplify your question. You want to stop java from updating oder you just want to stop java from suggesting to update ?

Comment: Found my solution. Just pushed this out at startup for all users and it doesn't ask anymore.

Comment: javaws -userConfig deployment.expiration.check.enabled false

Comment: alright. add that answer to your own question and later on you can mark it as the correct solution for your problem so other people, who are stuck on this problem, can see your solution